# VLookup and EXCEL

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula on column `O` to calculate the following:-

```
If E7 = N10 THEN 
  use O10 = M10
ELSE
  GET CURRENCY FROM E7
  MATCH E7 FROM D3:D5 and GET CORRESPONDING RATE FROM E3:E5 
  O10 = RATE * M10 / 100
END
```

I have the following formula BUT it does not include the default currency in `N10`

```
=M10 * VLOOKUP($E$7,$D$3:$E$5, 2, FALSE) / 100
```

Can anyone help?
[image: Excel sheet]

**edit** Basically I want column `O` to calculate the revenue by looking at column N and multiplying the rate that matches E3:E5. So If I:-

```
change E7 to EURO O10 becomes 160000 * 83 / 100
change E7 to USD O10 becomes 160000 * 155 / 100
change E7 to GBP O10 becomes 160000 * 100 / 100
```

Comment: So you want N7 to override E7, if there is something?

Comment: Does it not make more sense to match the values of N to the D3:E5 table

Comment: Yes If you can find the answer. Basically I want to be able to flick E7 to either GBP, Eur, USD and O10:O22 changes accordingly

Comment: I don't understand the logic though, lets say that $E$7 is GBP and we are dealing with row 18, then you want to convert the 160550 USD to GBP by the conversion rate of 1.55 right? So if you then change $E$7 to be Euro it doesn't make sense that that exchange value should still be 1.55

Comment: Also my experience of vlookup is that the table needs to be in alphabetical order... do you not need to swap GBP and Euro (i.e. D4 and D3)?

Comment: not related to the question, but you should rename Euro to EUR, if other currencies are abbreviated as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather use a grid of exchange rates like so:

```
    Euro    GBP  USD
Euro 100    127  165
GBP  83     100  155
USD  78     123  100
```

And then use Match and Index instead of vlookup to do a [2 way lookup](http://skp.mvps.org/xl00002.htm). So something along these lines:

```
=M10 * INDEX($E$3:$G$5, MATCH(N10,$E$2:$G$2,0), MATCH($E$7,$D$3:$D$5,0)) / 100
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood, I will try and put it into english, please see my edit

Comment: Really, both of you have "," instead of my ";"? Is that my locale?

Comment: hmmm... IF(N10 = $E$7, M10, M10 * VLOOKUP(N7,$D$3:$E$5, 2, FALSE) / 100), is this what you mean then? Leave E7 as a constant and let N7 define which rate you should be converting to...

Comment: Sorry, that should be N10 in the above comment:  IF(N10 = $E$7, M10, M10 * VLOOKUP(N7,$D$3:$E$5, 2, FALSE) / 100)

Comment: What is N7 ? its not in my equation

Comment: It should be two grids of data! I have just come to the same conclusion! Can you help me with match?

Comment: I think just 1 grid should be fine... I'll update my answer to use a grid and match in a minute

Comment: @Dan you **switched 2nd and 3rd argument** of the `INDEX` - this version will convert 100 USD (column matched by N10) into 155 GBP (row matched by $E$7)

Comment: or you got the exchange rates grid wrong? **100 USD = 64.5 GBP** given the exchange rate in question

Comment: @deathApril yeah either of those is true, I didn't really think of which way it was going. An obviously I just made up all the numbers. I'll switch the arguments in match and add more $

Answer (score 1):

you should multiply with the current rate and divide with the rate for currency in column `N`:

`=M10

 * INDEX($E$3:$E$5;MATCH($E$7;$D$3:$D$5;0))

 / INDEX($E$3:$E$5;MATCH(N10;$D$3:$D$5;0))`

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works:

```
=M10*VLOOKUP($E$7;$D$3:$E$5;2;FALSE)/100
```

Comment: But I I change E7 to another currency it doesnt! Sorry N10 is not included

Comment: Should be N10 instead of $N$7 if this is what the OP is asking for

Comment: If **E7** (the single one in red) is the switch cell, then I go back to my initial answer. Because that's what I checked.